# <gaia:DateTimePicker> does not align with grid in IE9

Tags: asp.net, html, css, internet-explorer-9, gaia

I have a popup form in asp that lists data in a table. In IE when the data exceeds a certain amount of rows you can scroll to look at the data, but if you wanted to update the date I have a DateTimePicker control. You click the button and a dropdown calendar shows.

The problem with IE is when you scroll and hit the button the calendar shows up in where the original button would have been when the page loaded. This causes an issue where you have to scroll down quite a ways.

It works perfect in firefox. Any suggestions?

```
<gaia:DateTimePicker ID="NewScheduledReviewDate" 
    runat="server" Width="90px" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" 
    cssclass="vistablue" SkinID="Calendar" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it, but probably not the right way. Firstly Safari and Firefox play off the style-sheet. IE only uses inline for this segment. BOTH are required for cross browser capabilities.